# How would you reference 'this' when the function calling 'this' is inside a child object's object?

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, object, this

I have the following setup, inside a module (Node), but this could be applicable anywhere.

```
function Storefront(){
    this.list = 'List';
    }

Storefront.prototype = {
    categories : {
             get : function(){
                   return this.list + ' here!';
                   }
             }
    }

module.exports = function(){
    if(!(this instanceof Storefront)) { return new Storefront(); }
    }
```

Later, I'm instantiating the object in another module as `sfront` and calling `sfront.categories.get();`.

Normally, it would be easy to just do a `var self = this;` inside a function, calling a child function inside of it and then referencing `self`. That doesn't work for obvious reasons: the object referencing 'this' is inside another object. I'm not quite sure how to pass the parent object Storefront's context into the child object's (categories) child property function 'get'. Right now it's pulling up as `'undefined'`, which is understandable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make `categories` a property:

```
Object.defineProperty(Storefront.prototype, 'categories', {
    get: function () {
        var storefront = this;

        return {
            get: function () {
                return storefront.list + ' here!';
            }
        };
    }
});
```

… which is a good argument for renaming the nested `get`. Depending on what `categories` should represent, though, it might be more appropriate to make it a different class entirely:

```
function StorefrontCategoryList(storefront) {
    this.storefront = storefront;
}

StorefrontCategoryList.prototype.get = function () {
    return this.storefront.list + ' here!';
};

function Storefront() {
    this.list = 'List';
    this.categories = new StorefrontCategoryList(this);
}
```

Comment: Yeah, this is exactly what I was considering; I wasn't sure if there was a way to do that with my current setup. I would of course rename the get function. @zerkms: In Node, each module is cached and returns the same object if that module is called later.

Comment: @zerkms: I’m not sure about an IIFE, but `bind()` could do it.

Comment: Instead of *that* (or *self*), consider something that indicates what *that* is, like `var storeFront = this`.

Comment: @RobG: I actually called it `self`, as in the question. `storefront` is better, yes.

Comment: It's all semantics I suppose, but *self* doesn't mean much to me either. :-(

Comment: @RobG: Sorry, the point was that it was just to match the question, not about one name versus another! I’ll edit that in, anyways; it’s my preferred style.

Comment: Definitely semantics - you guys are both correct in saying that naming it storefront or a readable name would be much better. 'self' is just used in so many places, it's easy to generalize it conceptually. That being said, any opinions on the second answer on this page?

Comment: @aamirl: `get categories()` is equivalent to this; I just used `Object.defineProperty` because it doesn’t require you to set the entire prototype using the same object literal.

Comment: @U2744SNOWFLAKE Talk about a brain freeze :( With both approaches it would be impossible for me to set the object foo.categories as a standalone; I suppose there really is no other way of doing this!

Answer (score 1):

Defining a `get`ter in an *Object literal*.

```
function Storefront(){
    this.list = 'List';
} 
Storefront.prototype = {
    get categories () {
        var self = this;
        return {
            "get": function () {
                return self.list + ' here!';
            }
        };
    }
};
(new Storefront()).categories.get(); // "List here!"
```

Although you lose the ability to set to `foo.categories`, you can now reference the instance easily.

This way will use more *cycles*, an alternative way is to give each instance it's own *categories* property directly (which can have a different inheritance chain) but that will use more *memory*

Comment: That is true - this would definitely work if I weren't setting foo.categories to another object; but that is something that could come up down the line as more modules are built and referencing the internal object as a standalone becomes more appropriate. It's a great, simple answer to the original question, though!